# WebDataRock - How can I add custom column next to Totals column, to put view button?

Tags: jquery, webdatarocks

I'd like to add a view button for each row that will redirect to another page for the detail view.
How can I add that column at the end while also rendering it in HTML? via jQuery.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebDataRocks is a tool for a visual representation of existing data. Therefore, it does not support adding custom columns.
Alternatively, you can create a separate column out of the component.